# in bash script, howto get the display-width of a String

Tags: bash, widechar

I want a bash function to count for the String Width that will comsumed when display.
because in my cases, String may contain some wide-charactors (e.g. Chinese). So I cannot just use the length of a string.

```
function getDisplayWidth ()
{
  ???
}
```

Then "abc" will return 3
and  "前后" should return 4 instead of 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your implementation of `wc` has the `-L` option, that appears to count the right "thing". (Coreutils has it, not sure if any other do.)

Ex:

```
$ getw() { wc -L <<< "$1"; }
$ getw 前后
4
$ getw 前a后c
6
$ getw abc前后
7
$ getw "行书 / 行書"
11
```

Comment: @Mat: Thanks, the one line function is fantastic!

Comment: @Mat: Dose it make any different if I add 'function' in front of getw, just like that in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try `wc -m`.  From the os x man page:

> The number of characters in each input file is written to the standard
>   output.  If the current locale does not support multibyte characters,
>   this is equivalent to the -c option.  This will cancel out any prior
>   usage of the -c option.

Comment: `wc -m` will give 2 with his sample Chinese text - there are only two chars.